# jQuery Найти первый подходящий элемент после заданного

Tags: jquery

Как можно найти первый подходящий элемент от заданного?
Т.е кликаем по первому элементу с классом test, а добавляем класс следующему элементу с классом test, причем неизвестно сколько элементов одного уровня между ними.

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="test ЖМЁМ НА НЕГО"></div>
        <div></div>
        Неизвестное количество элементов
        <div></div>
        <div class="test КЛАСС СЮДА"></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".parent .test").eq(0).click(function(){
  var el = $(this).nextAll(".test").first();
  console.log(el.attr("class"), el.text());
  el.addClass("red-text");
});
```

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="test ЖМЁМ НА НЕГО">First element</div>
  <div></div>
  Неизвестное количество элементов
  <div></div>
  <div class="test КЛАСС СЮДА">Second element</div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="test КЛАСС СЮДА">Third element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @br3t да, пардон

Comment: `next()` не лучше будет?

Comment: @br3t `next()` делает другое. Он берет только следующий элемент, если тот подходит под селектор.